# ILGenerator instantiate object and call instance method

Tags: c#, ilgenerator

I am trying to construct an instance of a generic type and call a method on that instance.  Then return the result of the method.

```
var genericType = typeof(GenericType<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TOutput));
il.DeclareLocal(genericType);
var instanceMethod = genericType.GetMethod("MethodName", new Type[0]);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, instanceMethod);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I keep getting a 'System.InvalidProgramExecution' exception.

GenericType class looks like this

```
public class GenericType<T>
{
    public T MethodName()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: An easy was to figure out the correct IL calls is to write the C# code for what you want to do, compile in release mode and then use ILDASM to see the IL.

Comment: You have to push the reference of the target object onto the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var il = mbuilder.GetILGenerator();
var genericType = typeof(GenericType<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TOutput));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, genericType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, genericType.GetMethod("MethodName", Type.EmptyTypes), null);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: So lets say I want to pass in a local parameter to the method "MethodName".  And that local variable is scoped to the method generating the IL.  local variable is named "myLocal" again scoped to the same level as genericType.

Comment: @Mike can you update a question or (even better) create a new one?

Comment: here is the new question.  thanks for your expertise.  I am working on completing the solution and looking at the generated IL code however this could be faster.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341097/ilgenerator-call-instance-method-with-parameter

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to figure out what IL you need to emit for a particular function is to write the code you want to generate by hand and then use [ILDASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) to see the IL created by the compiler.

**Here's an example...**

*C# method to duplicate...*

```
public static TOutput DoWork()
{
    var generic = new GenericType<TOutput>();
    var ret = generic.MethodName();
    return ret;
}
```

*Generated IL...*

```
.method public hidebysig static class App.TOutput 
DoWork() cil managed
{
    // Code size       15 (0xf)
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init ([0] class App.GenericType`1<class App.TOutput> generic,
            [1] class App.TOutput 'ret')
    IL_0000:  newobj     instance void class App.GenericType`1<class App.TOutput>::.ctor()
    IL_0005:  stloc.0
    IL_0006:  ldloc.0
    IL_0007:  callvirt   instance !0 class App.GenericType`1<class App.TOutput>::MethodName()
    IL_000c:  stloc.1
    IL_000d:  ldloc.1
    IL_000e:  ret
} // end of method Program::DoWork
```

*Example on how to emit and invoke this IL...*

```
var retType = typeof(TOutput);
var type = typeof(GenericType<>);
var genericType = type.MakeGenericType(retType);
var constructor = genericType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
var methodDef = genericType.GetMethod("MethodName", Type.EmptyTypes);

var newMethod = new DynamicMethod("MyMethod", retType, Type.EmptyTypes);
var generator = newMethod.GetILGenerator();
generator.DeclareLocal(genericType);
generator.DeclareLocal(retType);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructor);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, methodDef, null);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var ret = newMethod.Invoke(null, null);
Console.WriteLine(ret); // App.TOutput
```

*Supporting Classes...*

```
public class GenericType<T> where T : new()
{
    public T MethodName()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
public class TOutput
{
}
```