# ILGenerator call instance method with parameter

Tags: c#, ilgenerator

I am trying to construct an instance of a generic type and call a method on that instance. Then return the result of the method.

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = ...;
...
var genericType = typeof(GenericType<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TOutput));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, genericType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, methodInfo);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, genericeClientHelper.GetMethod("MethodName", new Type[] { typeof(MethodInfo) }));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I keep getting a 'System.BadImageFormatException: 'Bad class token.'' exception.

GenericType class looks like this

```
public class GenericType<T>
{
    public T MethodName(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of the code? Like, how are you constructing the type, how are you defining the method? Your current code looks fine (although `genericeClientHelper.GetMethod` should probably be `genericType.GetMethod`, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing the boundary between the **generated** program, and the **generating** program.

Specifically, your generating program, when run, constructs an instance of an object (a `MethodInfo` instance) and then attempts to generate a program that uses that instance - which it can't because that instance doesn't exist in the generated program, it exists in the memory of the generating program.

You have to construct the instance of `MethodInfo` inside your generated program - you have to write the Emit code to generate the IL that constructs the `MethodInfo` instance.

What you're trying to do makes about as much sense as doing the following:

```
Person person = new Person( "Antiduh", "United States" );

var genericType = typeof(GenericType<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TOutput));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, genericType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));

// This doesn't make sense. The object referred to by 
// my `person` variable doesn't exist in the generated program.
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, person);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, genericeClientHelper.GetMethod("MethodName", new Type[] { typeof(MethodInfo) }));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Thats problem number 1.

Problem number 2 is that you're using the wrong opcode when trying to provide an argument to a method - `Ldobj` doesn't do what you think it does.

Instead of using `Ldobj`, you'll have to load the reference by whatever means you fix your generation code to create the internal `methodInfo`. It'll probably be local, so you'll probably end up using `Ldloc` or some form thereof.

To come full circle, the reason why you're getting the error "Bad class token" is that the value that is supposed to follow `Ldobj` in the compiled IL is supposed to be a class metadata token. What you provided was not a class token, hence the error.

As a demonstration, below is a complete program that emulates what you're attempting to do.

```
private static void BuildAssembly()
{
    AssemblyName assemblyName;
    AssemblyBuilder assmBuilder;
    ModuleBuilder modBuilder;

    assemblyName = new AssemblyName( "Generated" );

    // Note the save directory is the directory containing this project's solution file.
    assmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        assemblyName,
        AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave,
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + @"\..\..\..\.."
    );

    modBuilder = assmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(
        assemblyName.Name,
        assemblyName.Name + ".dll",
        true
    );

    /*
     * public class GenericsDemo {
     * }
     */
    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType(
        "Generated.GenericsDemo",
            TypeAttributes.Public
    );

    BuildCallListMethod( typeBuilder );

    typeBuilder.CreateType();

    assmBuilder.Save( assemblyName.Name + ".dll" );
}

private static void BuildCallListMethod( TypeBuilder typeBuilder )
{
    // public void CallList() {
    //     List<object> list = new List<object>();
    //     object thing = new object();
    //     list.Add(thing);
    // }

    var listOfObject = typeof( List<object> );
    var objType = typeof( object );

    // public void CallList() { 
    var method = typeBuilder.DefineMethod( 
        "CallList", 
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, 
        CallingConventions.HasThis 
    );

    var gen = method.GetILGenerator();

    // List<int> list;
    var listLocal = gen.DeclareLocal( listOfObject );
    listLocal.SetLocalSymInfo( "list" );

    // object thing;
    var thingLocal = gen.DeclareLocal( objType );
    thingLocal.SetLocalSymInfo( "thing" );

    // list = new List<object>();
    gen.Emit( OpCodes.Newobj, listOfObject.GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes ) );
    gen.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc_0 );

    // thing = new object();
    gen.Emit( OpCodes.Newobj, objType.GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes ) );
    gen.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc_1 );

    // list.Add( thing );
    gen.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc_0 ); // loads `list`.
    gen.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc_1 ); // loads `thing`.
    gen.EmitCall( OpCodes.Callvirt, listOfObject.GetMethod( "Add" ), null );

    gen.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I knew the issue was with the MethodInfo being in the wrong layer I was hoping there was a way to send it to the generated method in a way that would work without tearing the data I need piece by piece.

Comment: As a note : The SetLocalSymInfo needs the emitSymbolInfo of DefineDynamicModule to be true (as it is in this answer) but the DefineDynamicModule is defined in both mscorlib.dll v4 (C# interactive panel for example) and System.Reflection.Emit.dll v6 (a .Net6 library Microsoft.NET.Sdk for example) which the System.Reflection.Emit.dll does not have the emitSymbolInfo parameter and SetLocalSymInfo.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36863

Comment: For the unsupported SetLocalSymInfo .net core problem we can use this :
var listBuilder = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(List<object>));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(List<object>).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, listBuilder);
// and on the call site :
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, listBuilder);